# tslint - Missing trailing comma (trailing-comma) on the last line

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I cannot figure out why my `tslint` even want to see the trailing comma on the end of the last line in the `objects`? How can I set the `ignore` rule for the last line of the objects for example? Thanks.

Exemple:

```
  props = {
    prop1: 21, // good
    prop2: 2, // good
    prop3: false // error: [tslint] Missing trailing comma (trailing-comma)

  }
```

Rule for `trailing-comma` in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"trailing-comma": [true, {
  "singleline": "never",
  "multiline": {
    "objects": "always",
    "arrays": "always",
    "functions": "never",
    "typeLiterals": "ignore"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You clearly have the rule enabled for multi-line objects:

```
"trailing-comma": [true, {
  "singleline": "never",
  "multiline": {
    "objects": "always",     // <==================
    "arrays": "always",
    "functions": "never",
    "typeLiterals": "ignore"
  }
}]
```

So...disable it by making that `"never"` (if you want to disallow commas there) or `"ignore"` (if you want to allow commas to be there or not, either way).

Comment: Oh, but in this case we shall to fully disable `trailing commas` for `object`, instead to make it disabled only for the last line in it. Is not?

Comment: @MaxTravis - The rule is for the last property, not each line. You have no choice about the commas *between* properties.

Comment: Thank you, but to be clearly, if I set the `"objects": "always"` to `never` or `ignore` it will disable this tslint rule for  whole object, that's incorrect... 

It will be:  `props = {
    prop1: 21,
    prop2: 2 
    prop3: false

  }` - on the `prop2` must be an error in tslint

Comment: @MaxTravis - `prop2: 2 prop3: false` is **already** a syntax error. This rule has nothing to do with it. This rule is purely about a comma after the **last** property before the closing `}` on the object initializer.

Comment: Ouch, I understood you now. Sorry for that, I just still a little bid confused after migration from .js to .ts ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in my `tslint.json` as following:

```
"rules": { "trailing-comma": false }
```

Answer (score 1):

Include trailing comma even in the last line is a good practice of having less merge conflict, although it looks weird.

Comment: I also like it cause when you are copying and pasting and changing lines order the comma there helps a lot!